# trigger function before file write operation

Tags: c, io

Let say we have a function:

```
void persist_result(FILE* to, unsigned char* b, int b_len) {...}
```

which would save some result in the given `FILE* to`.

Now I would like to get the data before the data is written to `to`, do something with it (assume encrypt it, etc..) and then call the actual IO operation, directly or indirectly.

One solution could be setting a buffer, but I don't know how to trigger my method for the encryption operation.

Also I was thinking to get some handle of file in memory, but don't know if there is any ISO way to do that?

Or any better solution?

Consider the following:

1. Size of the data need to be written by the `persist_result` is unknown, it could be 1 or more bytes.
2. I cannot change the source of `persist_result`.
3. No C++; it must be a portable C solution.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler thanks so much for suggest. Well I need to do the encryption operation before the plain data write operation. The encryption context is ready for work. I was thinking using the disk on memory, but is it ISO and can be used in Android NDK and iOS too? is it good practice? can be reliable?

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is the [Observer Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern).
When your function is called, actually you can first capture that call, do whatever you prefer and then continue with what you were doing. You could implement it in C using pointer to functions.

You can get inspiration from the following [example](https://github.com/cirocosta/observer-c)

Comment: Are observers allowed to modify the data that they observe?  The question seems to want to modify the data.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler that depends on your context, normally it would be thread safe if you work on a copy of the data.

Comment: In the 'Gang of Four' Observer Pattern, as I understand it, the observers would not be allowed to modify because then it matters which sequence the observers are executed in (because different observers for the same object might see different material if one of the observers modifies what it sees).  It's not a big deal — more of a nitpick.  I'm sure you can define 'pure observers' and 'mutating observers' and deal with the issues.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to capture every operation in standard C without changing the calls.  Things like encryption need context (like key) to work; that complicates life in general, but maybe `persist_result()` handles that automatically.  How will you handle things like `fseek()` or `rewind()`?

I think you are in for a world of pain unless you write your I/O operations to a non-standard C API that allows you to do what's necessary cleanly.  For example, your code might be written to call functions such as `pr_fwrite()`, `pr_putc()`, `pr_fprintf()`, `pr_vfprintf()`, `pr_fseek()`, `pr_rewind()`, etc — you probably wouldn't be applying this to either stdin or stdout — and have those do what's necessary.

If I were going to try this, I'd adopt prefixes (`pr_` and `PR`) and create a header `"prstdio.h"` to be used in place of, or in addition to, `<stdio.h>`.  It could contain (along with comments and header guards, etc):

```
#include <stdarg.h>
// No need for #include <stdio.h>

typedef struct PRFILE PRFILE;

extern PRFILE *pr_fopen(const char *name, const char *mode);
extern int pr_fclose(PRFILE *fp);
extern int pr_fputc(char c, PRFILE *fp);
extern size_t pr_fwrite(const void *buffer, size_t size, size_t number, PRFILE *fp);
extern int pr_fprintf(PRFILE *fp, char *fmt, ...);
extern int pr_vfprintf(PRFILE *fp, char *fmt, va_list args);
extern int pr_fseek(PRFILE *fp, long offset, int whence);
extern void pr_rewind(PRFILE *fp);
…
```

and all the existing I/O calls that need to work with the `persist_result()` function would be written to use the `prstdio.h` interface instead.  In your implementation file, you actually define the structure `struct PRFILE`, which would include a `FILE *` member plus any other information you need.  You then write those `pr_*` functions to do what's necessary, and your code that needs to persist results is changed to call the `pr_*` functions (and use the `PRFILE *` type) whenever you currently use the `stdio.h` functions.

This has the merit of being simply compliant with the C standard and can be made portable.  Further, the changes to existing code that needs to use the 'persistent result' library are very systematic.

In a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43955899/trigger-function-before-file-write-operation/43956157#comment74943165_43955899) to the main question — originally responding to a now-deleted comment of mine (the contents of which are now in this answer) — the OP asked:

> I need to do the encryption operation before the plain data write operation. The encryption context is ready for work. I was thinking using the disk on memory, but is it ISO and can be used in Android NDK and iOS too?

Your discussion so far is in terms of encrypting and writing the data.  Don't forget the other half of the I/O equation — reading and decrypting the data.  You'd need appropriate input functions in the header to be able to handle that.  The `pr_ungetc()` function could cause some interesting discussions.

The scheme outlined here will be usable on other systems where you can write the C code.  It doesn't rely on anything non-standard.  This is a reasonable way of achieving data hiding in C.  Only the implementation files for the `prstdio` library need know anything about the internals of the `PRFILE` structure.

Since 'disk in memory' is not part of standard C, any code using such a concept must be using non-standard C.  You'd need to consider carefully what it means for portability, etc.  Nevertheless, the external interface for the `prstdio` library could be much the same as described here, except that you might need one or more control functions to manipulate the placement of the data in memory.  Or you might modify `pr_fopen()` to take extra arguments which control the memory management.  That would be your decision.  The general I/O interface need not change, though.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I really appreciate it (hope it's not off-topic). Well I think I got confused too much now, let say the `persist_data` is a shared/dynamic object call. I think I got it somehow to define the operations required for `IO`, and pass my implementation. But now how? if I could change the source, so I would define a new way to let do all encryption stuffs and then write on file. Still trying to figure it out. Thanks for your answer again, awesome.